# Windows 10 doesn't reflect new emoji font from Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I downloaded the Windows 11 ISO and got the latest emoji font file (v1.35) from: `sources\install.wim\1\Windows\Fonts\seguiemj.ttf`

Then since I couldn't replace the system font from within Windows as it gets being reverted to v1.29 after I copy over it, I booted into a Linux live USB and replaced the file from Linux's file manager.

Now Windows properly shows the v1.35 font, however, going to https://getemoji.com/ still shows the old Windows emojis.

Is there a cache somewhere that I should clear up or something for my changes to reflect? I've already rebooted multiple times and I've checked and the font version is still the new v1.35 one.

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you just update to the version of Windows that updates the file properly? Why are you just updating the file?

Comment: @Ramhound because that file is on Windows 11, I'm on Windows 10 and I don't want to update to Windows 11 yet. It still lacks some of the features that I use on Windows 10. I just want the updated emojis.

Comment: You probably need to sort out what you really need. Windows 11 is here and moving forward. Windows 10 is steadily moving toward death.

Comment: Did you try installing it rather than copying and replacing the file?

Comment: @Destroy666 similar to what I stated in my post above, when I try to install the new font while in the Windows environment itself, it reverts back to the old 1.29 version

Comment: @user9564371 - In the past when I research this topic, I discovered that operating system kernels are also updated when the Emoji(s) are updated. You won't be able to accomplish the task of just updating the font for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no need to copy file.

Just right click the `seguiemj.ttf` file, then choose `install` or `install for all users`. That's all.

I have tried it minutes ago, it works. And after I restarted my PC, it is still there, no revert.

Comment: Does it update how the emoji looks in your system too?

Comment: Sure. Maybe you should just have a try. BTW, if you do as what I said, the new Segoe UI Emoji is co-existing with the old one at present. If you don't need the old one any more, or you want to roll back, you can just uninstall the relevant font.